# Por qué el useState de React imprime 2 veces en consola?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un navbar básico para ir reutilizando y quería un state para ir modificando e ir haciendo pruebas pero en la consola me imprime 2 veces. Este es el código

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navegador = ({ btn }) => {
    const [ubicacion, cambioUbicacion] = useState(false);

    console.log(ubicacion);
    return (
        <nav>
            <div className="nav-wrapper blue">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link
                            to={"/Login"}
                            className="waves-effect waves-light btn deep-purple accent-2"
                        >
                            {btn}
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Navegador;
```

Y así se ve en la consola del navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No es cuestión del useState, es un comportamiento normal de react si estás usando <React.StrictMode> al inicializar tu aplicacion.

Comment: y cómo lo corrijo? porque intento hacer una condicional con el y me salta error porque react no lo renderizó para evitar un bucle infinito

Comment: Puedes colocar el resto de código que indicas sobre lo que quieres realizar y poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Tal vez el componente padre de Navegador hace otro renderizado y por eso se muestra dos veces. Podrías validar que tu estado este definido y además sea falso o true, como lo tengas que hacer

Comment: si estas utilizando hooks en el componente padre del mismo, es común que este se muestre dos veces en la consola, ya que se genera un cambio y react lo actualiza, es por eso que se muestra la primera vez que el componente es llamado, y si hay un "setState" en el componente padre, se volverá a ejecutar

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: No hay nada que corregir, este es el comportamiento normal de una aplicación React creada con [`create-react-app`](https://create-react-app.dev/). Esto únicamente está presente en "modo desarrollo", en modo producción desaparece.

React viene con lo que se conoce como [`StrictMode`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), básicamente es una herramienta para determinar problemas potenciales en la aplicación.

De la [documentación oficial](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects):

> El modo estricto no puede detectar efectos secundarios de forma automática por ti, pero te puede ayudar a encontrarlos al hacerlos un poco más deterministas. Esto se logra al invocar dos veces las siguientes funciones:

- Los métodos `constructor`, `render` y `shouldComponentUpdate` de los componentes de clase
- El método estático `getDerivedStateFromProps` de los componentes de clase
- El cuerpo de los componentes de función
- Funciones de actualización del estado (el primer argumento de `setState`)
- Las funciones que se pasan a `useState`, `useMemo` o `useReducer` **Tu caso**

Comment: entiendo pero necesito hacer una condicional con ese state y me marca error el navegador `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop`, si lo hago en un context no habría ese problema?

Comment: Ese es otro problema que no se relaciona con lo que preguntas. Comparte con nosotros (si puedes) un link hacia el proyecto así te podemos ayudar. Puedes usar la plataforma [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new)